# Is there any way to supply the allowDiskUse option to an mongoose.js aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm running an aggregation on a collection of around 300k+ records which requires several unwinds and regroups. I'm hitting the following error;

```
'exception: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn\'t allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.'
```

I can't seem to work out how to pass this option through using the mongoose.js API?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We don't have a helper for this right now, but an `allowDiskUse()` helper function will be included in Mongoose 3.8.12, which I'll ship today: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2114

If you want an immediate solution or don't want to upgrade to 3.8.12 (although upgrading is recommended), you can do something like:

```
var aggregation = MyModel.aggregate(...); 
aggregation.options = { allowDiskUse: true }; 
aggregation.exec(function() {});
```

Comment: how to use with promises?

Answer (score 24):

```
Model.aggregate(..).allowDiskUse(true).exec(callback)
```

[mongoose api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
const agg = Model.aggregate(..).option({ allowDiskUse: true });
```

worked for me as per the Mongoose V6.0.4 documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-option)

Answer (score 0):

> const data = await Model.aggregate([..]).option({ allowDiskUse: true }).explain();

Source - [Mongoose explain API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#Aggregate.prototype.explain())